# In PhpStorm 2020.3.1 bookmarks list is lost

Tags: phpstorm

I moved from PhpStorm 2019.2.5 to PhpStorm 2020.3.1 and all configuration data were copied, except bookmarks (clicking <kbd>Shift + F11</kbd>) Also creating new bookmarks in my project I see in some time that bookmarks list is empty.

Is it some options? I searched under Settings menu and did not find any relative settings...

**MODIFIED :**
Yes, I have directory ~/.PhpStorm2019.2 and inside of it subdirectory :

```
~/.PhpStorm2019.2/config/workspace$ ls -la
total 2176
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  root  12288 Feb 11 08:39 .
drwxrwxrwx 20 root  root   4096 Feb 14 14:38 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   5414 Apr  4  2020 1a4w1gfzxLk3XpeRcXCGguCZerY.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  18537 May 31  2020 1a4yiM7iQLMU5BgjHz9PV2emErm.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  30598 Apr 10  2020 1a9JNxNHut8vFqg5Gnttsx2kMFk.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2519 Apr  8  2020 1aF1O7im5ARC1oA848mL32YbgJy.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  31350 Apr 12  2020 1aLluLCshipPI8PLdvL8YKuvdBM.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  15708 Apr 13  2020 1aQevHaJ9Qm1Xu1ynMe9M3KWLar.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  34798 May 14  2020 1aTRfKcAhlNrAFR6TgCySFO9nSo.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  32498 Jul 31  2020 1bd8rM6zpBWTk5GnGhFdLmXNLTs.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  33860 Jul 11  2020 1bfOzG3bFNBq0wtXfvcOQx7QZOU.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  30769 May 11  2020 1bhtho9junW4mUenLypSIOoNaVm.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  37002 Oct  5 13:36 1bkcANAwZe58iKfq0UJjfl66Kju.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2441 May  2  2020 1bKv1R7F4LNt40noNvr3Py20NB8.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2091 May  2  2020 1bKvTqaX66TUvVXYxsfcz901bgC.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   8688 May 31  2020 1bKwS8cAOyMAX94IMG9iyYOQTPn.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  11829 May  5  2020 1bTI7NNOpytER1F61hCb3lhjgwV.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  16100 May 13  2020 1bTR60wheJGpEF799gVsB1Lz02Q.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2139 May 14  2020 1btubG7f2rqoGXBnH875B2yXZw9.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  37970 Feb  4 11:50 1btulPnfEviYu6ZjA0jMz3XAGKV.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   4250 Jun  2  2020 1clEqS1Wq1v8r4Wr98Cdq6SG7k6.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   5932 Jun  2  2020 1clF3Am650wORZvKDgJxBDcFBiH.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   3923 Jun  2  2020 1clFb4IM1vl9MIyrrokkkn4vZ5j.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  33371 Feb 13 09:42 1clGIH90kWyK19fWs1HGSL2pRGR.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  43127 Jan 25 11:00 1ctGMqtntGULseCbqHKs9v8xxe4.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  31896 Jan 18 15:13 1ctK6MJCImTjbz5Ox0u8IDYo3ba.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  23555 Feb  2 09:35 1dGSvEK8fGX3m4EfGXZ49sY0q6u.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  36238 Aug  4  2020 1egJwlcgyrfMz1jyLxdILRLgWOI.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  37897 Feb  7 09:57 1eXXs2titWFF7TZU9w8rkBAhHj8.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  32467 Feb 12 19:38 1fcVuiQ1KzM84cFTwdjUP6xvJgR.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  32481 Feb  7 10:40 1fR5HYJb9mtyR8FtQQauoAjcvRM.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2137 Aug 12  2020 1fzkA8gM539XI3tEfvsgezxoAe6.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  19396 Aug 17  2020 1g8aQVf2HPSO9pAQ4Qu1KjRAF1w.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   4348 Aug 19 06:49 1gHEM0N53OlPzE0xV3nQJjgbbhK.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  35322 Dec 21 14:51 1gjK6igFfcUFIZ46nWj6oNvexBu.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  5038 Oct  2 14:44 1iJudFQ4hlAVsXUsW8R5WYzLgZZ.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  8173 Dec 12 10:56 1iKHDerprVcFOQbs8Tx7ppMfxAM.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 10180 Oct  4 15:11 1iPMoBCOhdSAEF9DiVJUZpe7cXD.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 36389 Feb  8 18:40 1jh4C3pQhWek7GCdFV6oOUeEe15.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  7289 Oct 30 17:54 1jKS80A3gOig5uu8dqztMAGUMsX.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  4274 Oct 28 07:39 1jQJWXPdCne1x3BxeZYH76Sn25L.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 32697 Feb  8 18:47 1jUfLDHy6rFBnAamAL4OBF1QPoQ.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 24820 Jan 21 16:36 1kleDQZqIJX0U2gLSTXul5cJW3k.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  2061 Nov 26 07:28 1koYZJDKe2ZnIJLtghgFwa95W7s.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 12630 Nov 28 08:01 1ksSBjqCHFseVKdvzL4gXCVSFEf.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 18984 Jan 15 15:00 1kuBY5e27EaELWznLHt4dFoOEx8.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 15310 Dec  7 15:10 1kuMl0WELNfbzuNDWs0qnrZZ9M4.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  3561 Dec 15 11:01 1lek8uPBphwtJiiOZehepwlRIZ5.xml                                                                                                                                           
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  2200 Dec  7 19:01 1lFItAEOrMZ2JIj8ckoduLcOYjZ.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 11337 Dec 19 07:23 1ljFlfClFyKvLIBxNrMzoguYhfi.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 24929 Feb  8 06:40 1lKxmKjKRBSY09HFZW2BYuWhLkP.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 34255 Feb  6 07:44 1lNYJEKjvBuq35dsNWP2sPO88S7.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 37624 Feb 14 10:58 1lSkUerkZ2rf0XNQ6z4LVUeZlMU.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 33419 Jan 10 09:30 1lTufuXvYLIgYcSQ3Y6QAQ9DNjh.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  4894 Dec 21 18:52 1lxd5ToFnNIvccCI7YVY6oW8dbg.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 31395 Jan 29 15:08 1m3eXdt2CqEgv5bggUR4noHSygj.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  4388 Jan 29 15:08 1m3uD2lWCplwU10e1JqTHdUXqcP.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 10925 Dec 25 09:16 1m8MahHOw3BvTGdkXvfBPaMyVcx.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  8771 Jan  5 15:01 1mdv8IQtJyWdail2TCiPN7BoVCF.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  8199 Jan 10 09:04 1mrf4cb4ER4rzwVNMNiBJ8Y7y3e.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  8850 Feb  5 18:51 1naoB9qzi2HWn7ssr8zurscg6bz.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 28242 Feb 14 14:38 1oBmeqCErUo2GelWqStF2ixql1v.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  3076 Feb  8 07:08 1oBXIchRN149qCLmNHO6Q7rdQRy.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 13013 Feb  8 09:10 1oBXtjLGDdSAuiFibXz1ZIkxUws.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge 26956 Feb 14 14:24 1oH8QdZPVx9tOD0Ww1TsWVMG5x8.xml
-rw-rw-r--  1 serge serge  2537 Feb 11 09:06 1oKBfsMSY7Uv9DGdKNBR9d88fS2.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  34290 Feb  4 19:03 1Rm4AxUdFncCarLk3cvlZoW6hPG.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  39992 Nov  8  2019 1Rmi5cfkZdj4lbwNRpU84eKp2wP.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  33598 Nov 19  2019 1Rmsg9zY18B6tDflh2cW9EUGnzo.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  34394 Mar 26  2020 1RpDtKaNvSbIuuQKmK1spjIAGBP.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  19420 Jan 27  2020 1RsB0AIxbLGLyP68lzaDwJVwugW.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2092 Oct  7  2019 1RsgPDExoMZrfSFD7yQt9jW9kus.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  13765 Oct 21  2019 1S41LVlLjHZuzyNOpUP9gAyQEqC.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  14130 Feb 23  2020 1SmpfiiZmHeqSCJFohplSImPLEO.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   9701 Nov 12  2019 1SpeqqddT3TTAxPKQM5yRbftnBf.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   6881 Nov  9  2019 1T0x0jGYfUVdB8qUJt3tzoqzNw2.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   9992 Nov 14  2019 1TCBYpfPutkKefcU3Z65ewW9tWT.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  11594 Nov 15  2019 1Tdb0KLEuevg5K8fwis8wVm1hKp.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  21733 Dec 28  2019 1TegnKDlmFkn8XO9vKzLHbvnkNw.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  37574 May  9  2020 1Tk6cIdSmoymNKD76QMTISwqFjv.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2432 Nov  8  2019 1TK9E8IAzmHyPp68ls0tNgPVayD.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  40374 May 10  2020 1TK9kipvhSN5PW40W9Q5MX8BgiN.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  33869 May  8  2020 1TyEKu6gQ8KqIy5EHM8e1DFWKra.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   4199 Dec 19  2019 1VBeuWsaVbO09Of5oZC9THjo93d.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   5165 Dec 30  2019 1Vhv8g0qJ3s8ddSUFnT64jg2RH8.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  22540 Jan 29  2020 1Vjg3bEBOCT8rJrsTiH7l92CNQl.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2978 Dec 31  2019 1VjXSbFCiF6ZA6yPRAhvXHg9N56.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  11044 Dec 24  2019 1VMvp2Yvn56OXpbj5VOEGeCDCe6.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   3149 Dec 23  2019 1VNIaZBaxfVgloLcYmducbMH3cv.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  16113 Jan  1  2020 1VPwNXU603DVMBQmUkGqjGUdjZX.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   5916 Jan  3  2020 1VqUiFHCkE6G6SGc9s9NaktrFsk.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  34674 Jun  5  2020 1Vrzjgo5fcnGzdrJWKIUellZNhZ.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   4971 Jan  3  2020 1Vs7kGPSXQ9BzmCWgyGjjPa22yk.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  21969 Jan 27  2020 1Vs986PKMCK9MxUFwrD9Ek0Tehr.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   7796 Jan 10  2020 1W4eGRWFs7dRZBQwkTSxSJw7pxW.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   9793 Jan  7  2020 1W4VJrk0J31KWw3ERy1bERdMhGR.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   5093 Jan 10  2020 1WC7XeeIYoGHyfBjIrNESRHSWX3.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   3434 Jan 10  2020 1WCXAwWIxaEa9EbVOkVr5x3kkNJ.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   5308 Jan 14  2020 1WN2kmt0G72TBta2suHkS6pCCtO.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  35152 Jun 13  2020 1Wz7P6rGxq0V2l19QzEEi6r2iAO.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2239 Jan 31  2020 1X7a8SVRQv8b1uELcN7KJF3TY9h.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2240 Feb 28  2020 1X7YgiWmhP74klYNmmoXIKOSs1v.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2145 Mar  5  2020 1Yi4PzB92Z6e4wCly3e2sJYosS6.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2450 Mar  7  2020 1YmkrsfXhp0aeumDMWAGZFsSbSU.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   4586 Feb 28  2020 1YR8NaUhpjLA0EDW4led9eCZgWV.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  24885 Mar 28  2020 1YRTdgIEBLC1S4OLHsptdZa1S00.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  27424 Sep  3 14:25 1YTMYeYiyXb5GJKJJjz6jV8ITET.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  26931 Mar 16  2020 1Z51nNPaJ2wJXIZCpaAAS8l8vVa.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2093 Mar 25  2020 1Zcae8ilyi77Ute4Rw0HG64hsDl.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   2146 Mar 16  2020 1ZCHRrbmDJDlvAOrE31t9cRQj84.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  20513 Mar 16  2020 1ZDC0iWrUwv9jF5dlxiJxn7886T.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  25177 Apr  8  2020 1ZDc1if7TEFkcZXmymhgQVndCf1.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  42734 Dec 13 18:21 1ZfXA78cN7EP8Swa8brm8jI9Mh3.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   7588 Mar 28  2020 1ZkAcAAGWo7tvGSmEwrCgT5UpA2.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  33749 Apr  5  2020 1Zkr2pePj2cwRKZ4SuyfVHzFcAA.xml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  root   4191 Apr  2  2020 1ZyAFVx1YA2coSliSpgUMfWiUkU.xml
```

I opened file : /.idea/workspace.xml of my project and it has no any “projectID” parameter.

No specific directory for 2020.3.1 under home.

Also I see menu items “File”->“Manage IDE Settings”->"Import Settings"->"Export Settings".
Could it be usefull in my case?

Comment: Actually, bookmarks are being stored in the "config/workspace/<id>.xml" file under "BookmarkManager" component node.

You can get project ID from the project ".idea/worskpace.xml" file ("projectID" node, looks like "1oAhIKujxVxS6G7rEN3iofx3LdY")

Config directory is different for various OS'es, please check the following article:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory

Basically, the idea is to compare specific workspace XML files for both 2019.2.5 and 2020.3.1 installations, you still should have an older config directory on your workstation.

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED